# CSS Rule for specific string in Input

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, input

Is it possible to apply CSS rules to a specific string of letters inside an input box. For example, if the string is `ing` and the user inputted `playing`, just the letters "ing" would show up as a different color.

It is my understanding that inputs cannot contain HTML, so one workaround would be to hide the input and turn its value into HTML so that I could surround the matching text with a `<span>`. However, this gets rid of the cursor and text highlighting, so this solution does not work for me. I am using React.

Thank you!

Comment: No there is no way to do that with `<input>` elements. You will have create a custom input system using `<div>` element.

Comment: Well that sucks. Do you know of any libraries that do this or should I make my own custom input?

Comment: You don't need a library. Just use contenteditable to true for div and it will work like input element

Comment: @MaheerAli Oh, perfect. Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure if it will work perfect for you. But try it out

Comment: @MaheerAli I think I will get it to work for my project. It's not very complex, I'll just have to make my own placeholder system